# A problem about weak topology or topology equivalence

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I have a problem with the proof of the following theorem:

Suppose that $X$ is a normed space, and that $\mathcal{T}$ is a topology on $X$ such that each $\mu \in X^*$ is continuous with respect to $\mathcal{T}$. Show that $\sigma\left(X,X^*\right)\subseteq \mathcal{T}$, where $\sigma\left(X,X^*\right)$ is the weak topology.

Here's my proof.

Let $\{x_i\}_{i\in I}$ be convergent to $x$ w.r.t $\mathcal{T}$. So $\forall \mu\in X^*$, $\mu\left(x_i\right)\rightarrow \mu\left(x\right)$, since $\mu$ is continuous w.r.t $\mathcal{T}$. Thus, $x_i \rightarrow x$ in weak sense, ie. the net is convergent w.r.t $\sigma\left(X,X^*\right)$. Thus,
$$x_i\rightarrow x \,\, \text{in} \,\,\mathcal{T}\Rightarrow x_i\rightarrow x \,\,\text{in} \,\,\sigma\left(X,X^*\right).$$
Let $\mathcal{O}$ be an open set in $\mathcal{T}$. $X$\ $\mathcal{O}$ is an closed set w.r.t $\mathcal{T}$. Thus, $\forall x\in S=X$\ $\mathcal{O}$, we can find a net $x_i\rightarrow x$ w.r.t $\mathcal{T}$ in $S$, where $x_i\neq x$. By the previous argument, $x_i\rightarrow x$ w.r.t $\sigma\left(X,X^*\right)$. So, $S$ is closed in $\sigma\left(X,X^*\right)$, thus, $\mathcal{O}$ is open in $\sigma\left(X,X^*\right)$. which implies $\mathcal{T} \subseteq \sigma\left(X,X^*\right)$.

But what the theorem wants me to prove is the reverse. So, what's the problem inside my proof?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof is wrong. You are proving that $x\in X-O$ is the limit of a net in $X-O$ with the topology $\sigma(X,X^*)$. But this is trivially true always (for any $x$); it suffices to take the constant net $x_i=x$. Note that it could be other points that are in the closure $\overline{X-O}$ with respect to  $\sigma(X,X^*)$ but not in $X-O$, therefore $X-O$ is not necessarily closed in $\sigma(X,X^*)$.

On the other hand, what you really have is that the identity

$id:(X,\mathcal{T})\rightarrow(X,\sigma(X,X^*))$

is continuous; this means that $\sigma(X,X^*)\subset \mathcal{T}$.

Another comment: you say that $\{x_i\}$ is a sequence, however I am sure that you mean that it is a net. Note that neither $\sigma(X,X^*)$ nor $\mathcal{T}$ have necessarilly a countable neighborhood base at $0$.

Comment: Yes, $\{x_i\}$ is a net. I get the point that $id$ is a continuous function. But I don't understand the first two paragraphs of your answers. If $\mathcal{O}$ is an open set w.r.t $\mathcal{T}$, why isn't $X-\mathcal{O}$ necessarily closed in $\mathcal{T}$?

Comment: Sorry, I have corrected the typos. I wanted to mean $\sigma(X,X^*)$. The point is that you are not really proving that $X-O$ is closed w.r.t. $\sigma(X,X^*)$.

Answer (score 0):

As Littlefield said, you can always find a trivial net $x_{\alpha} \to x$, if we just take $x_{\alpha} = x$ for all $\alpha \in A$ (some index set). What you would need to show (to prove this false claim) is that for any $\mathcal{T}$ neighborhood around $x \in X \backslash O$, denoted $N(x)$, there exists some $y \in N(x)$ with $y \neq x$ such that $y \in X\backslash O$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. Could you make it more clear what you are trying to prove?

Comment: that $\mathcal{T} \subset \sigma(X,X^*)$.

Comment: Could u write it down step by step? I'm slow in understand it.